# General concept of filtrations of algebraic structures

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, soft-question

### Question

What is the essence, the general idea, behind the concept of a **filtration** of an algebraic structure?

### Background

From linear algebra, I know that a **filtration** of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ is basically a chain of subspaces of the form
$$
\{ 0 \} = V_0 \subseteq V_2 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq V_{n-1} \subseteq V_n = V, \qquad V_j = \ker\left( (f-\lambda\mathrm{id}_V)^j \right),
$$
for all $0 \leq j \leq n$. In other words, the $V_j$ are the eigenspaces of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ belonging to an endomorphism $f : V \to V$. I learned that such filtrations are used interim to determine a Jordan normal form.

Neither was I told where this concept comes from, nor where else it might be useful. However, I remember to have read in an algebra book that the chain of subgroups
$$
\{ e \} = G_0 \subseteq G_2 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq G_{n-1} \subseteq G_n = G
$$
is useful for $\ldots$ whatever$-$unfortunately, I cannot recall the details anymore$-$, telling me that filtrations are more than just an interim tool to determine Jordan normal forms in linear algebra.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(mathematics)